# Express4.js - route only if there is an active passport.js session

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

I am using passport.js and express4.js. I would like to know if there is an automatic way to verify if the client as opened a session with passport.js when he try to access a view?

Actually I am doing like this to verify if the client can access an url:

```
router.get('/[0-9]{3}/', function(req, res, next){
    var path_codecs = req.originalUrl.split('/')[2];

    if (!req.user) {
        res.redirect('/login');
    } 
    if (req.user.dataValues.codecs !== path_codecs) {
        next();
    }
    res.render('decoupage')
});
```

Do I have to do this verification at each view I want to restrict to session user or is there a more automatic way to define what views can be accessed and not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`req.user`](http://passportjs.org/docs/authenticate#sessions) (which Passport will set after a successful authentication).

I usually use this in a thin middleware like so:

```
function isAuthenticatedMiddleware (req, res, next) {
  if (req.user) { return next(); }

  next('AuthenticationError');
}

router.get('/[0-9]{3}/', isAuthenticatedMiddleware, function(req, res, next){
```

You can easily add this to *all* routes on a router with express's [`router.all`](http://expressjs.com/api.html#router.all)

```
router.all('*', isAuthenticatedMiddleware);
```